# How do I Add PHP code in WordPress POST without using a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add php code(2000 lines) to WordPress post manually without using any plugin or third party tool. But I have not been successful in this... If anybody knows how I can do this please feel free to post an answer. So far I have been able to add my php code to WP Page but not WP Post. I will be looking forward to you! Thanks!

Comment: How were you able to add php code into a page?

Comment: It's Simple just go to your theme folder in my case it was "twentytwentytwo" then create a .php file there and add the following code in it                                                "<?php /*

Template Name: Show Data

 */ ?>"               after adding this code add this code in the next line "<?php get_header() ?>" and then under this get header line youu can paste your php code. then go to you WP admin in pages section edit anyone of the page and then select your theme name from the dropdown menu of themes which in your case will be "Show Data". then publish.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this by creating a separate .php file in my theme "twentytwentytwo" folder and then I pasted the following code in it...

"<?php
/*

- Template Name: new Theme
- Template Post Type: post
  */
  ?>"

""
""

By doing this I created a Separate theme for my post. Then simple pasted my php code under the get_header() line....
After this I logged in to my WP admin and clicked on the edit post and in the template dropdown section I found my theme name "new Theme" just selected that and published. Job done!

Comment: Nice. You could have also edited `single.php` or similar theme file in order to catch all pages, or archive page, or even by custom-tag etc. Learn more [template hierarchi](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) .

Answer (score 0):

Use 'the_content' filter https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/

example :

```
function custom_content($content)
{
    global $post;
    
    if ($post && $post->post_type == 'post') {
        
        if ($post->ID == '145'()) { // target a specific post by ID
            // do something
        }
    }
    
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'custom_content');
```

Comment: Thank You for your reply! I am glad to know this method but I have found another way to do it...